# how to execute %0d pattern of ffmpeg from .bat file

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg

I have a ffmpeg command:
ffmpeg -i D:\Wildlife.wmv -f image2 D:\dfs\image-%07d.png
It work when I parse into command prompt directly. 
But when I saved it into a .bat file, "%0" in %07d pattern became the file's name.

So how do I execute this ffmpeg command from a .bat file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double the `%` to be `%%`, and it should work.